# Socket.io kick specific user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an event from the client side that passes the socket id to be kicked to the server, `socket.emit('kick', socketId);`.
My intention is to find the socket using this `socketId` server side, and then call `socketToBeKicked.disconnect()`.  How do I find the specific socket? I tried looking at other posts but most of the solutions do not work anymore. Or is there a better way that I can implement the kick function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Instead of trying to find the socket obj on the server side, we can emit an event from the server to the client to that is going to get kicked and emit another event back to the server to get the client's socket obj.

**client.js**

```
socket.emit('kick', socketId); // sent by the host

socket.on('kick helper', () => { // sent by the user getting kicked
    socket.emit('kick helper');
}
```

**server.js**

```
socket.on('kick', (socketId) => {
    socket.to(socketId).emit('kick helper');
}

socket.on('kick helper', () => { // now this socket obj is the user getting kicked
    socket.disconnect(); 
}
```

It still feels like quite a long way around to get the socket object of the user to be kicked. Please share if you have a better solution, I would love to know!

Comment: This also has the downside of relying on the client to respond to that "ping" so that you can kick it.  We usually maintain an array of the websocket objects that we attach other data to (the user object, for example) so that we can target which sockets we are destroying more easily.